# After Social login,product is not adding to wishlist niether not redirecting to wishlist page

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I am facing issue adding product in wishlist (magento version 2.2.3).

Here is scenario,

Step 1 :- Make sure customer not logged in.

Step 2 :- Go to product list page and click "Add to wishlist"

Step 3 :- it will redirected to login page.

Step 4 :- Now after social login it may be facebook,google you can check product not added in wishlist.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11825

Comment: That solution worked for normal login but not working on soacial login - @MuhammadHasham